# Realm, searching in String list

Tags: android, performance, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-list

I have an items (RealmObject) and they have barcodes (RealmList).
I have to query which item contains a searched barcode.

```
public class Item extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;
    private RealmList<String> barcodes;
```

I have tried this but its too slow because I have a lot of item and the items have several barcode:

```
for (Item item : realm.where(Item.class).findAll()) {
                    if (item.getBarcodes().contains(barcode)) {
                        itemId = item.getId();
                        return;
                    }
                }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that list of primitive support **querying**, but you can create new class `Barcode` that extends `RealmObject` with String field

```
public class Barcode extends RealmObject{
   private String barcodeId;
}
```

then replace `RealmList<String> barcodes` to `RealmList<Barcode> barcodes` then query like this

```
RealmResult<Item> realmResult = realm.where(Item.class).equalTo("barcodes.barcodeId",barcode).findAll();
```

Also you can add **@Index** annotation that will improve querying speed(but writing may be a bit slower) [docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#indexing-properties)

```
public class Barcode extends RealmObject{
      @Index
       private String barcodeId;
    }
```